# tengo un array con una estructura y deseo conseguir un algortimo para conseguir otro tipo de estructura

Tags: php

array_type_services: Esta es la estructura principal.

La posición de cada elemento que se encuentra dentro del array_type_services forma parte de una misma entidad. por ejemplo:

```
array_type_services_example = [
    'fabricante'=>['company-1-a','company-2-a'],
    'instalador' =>['company-1-b','company-2-b'],
    'distribuidor' =>['company-1-c','company-2-c']
];
```

y quiero obtener un array_final con la siguiente estructura

```
array_type_services[ 
    ['company-1-a','company-1-b','company-1-c'],
    ['company-2-a','company-2-b','company-2-c'] 
];
```

Es un intento, pero debo recorrer la primera estructura 4 veces con el mismo indice del segundo y no logro generar ese algoritmo.

```
    const PARSE_HEADERS_ORDER = [
        'fabricante',
        'instalador',
        'distribuidor',
        
    ];
```

```
    public function restructuring_data($ajax_data)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $data_array = $ajax_data[self::PARSE_HEADERS_ORDER[$i]];

            for ($j = 0 ; $j <= count($data_array); $j) {
                $j=[];
               
                array_push( $j ,$data_array[$j]);

                if(count($j)> 4 ){
                    $ajax_data['company_group'] = [];
                    array_push( $ajax_data['company_group'] ,$j);
                };

                if ($i == '3'){
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo una cosa... ¿partes de un array o de dos? Y por favor... edita el último fragmento de código (el tercero), porque no se entiende lo que querías poner

Comment: gracias @VFG. Ya lo edito. pero basicamente parto de un Array.

Comment: Se entiende mejor @VFG ?

Comment: Se entiende mejor. Hay un problema y es que no muestras un intento de solución. A parde de eso... se entiende que al final el array resultante tendrá siempre el mismo número de elementos que `$array_type_services_example['fabricante']`, ¿verdad?

Comment: Tienes razón, no he colocado un intento de solución porque no he llegado a nada que sirva o que de camino a una solución. me siento estancado. por otra parte, sí!  la longitud del array_resultante = $array_type_services_example['fabricante']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema extraño, porque no se me ocurre en qué circunstancia se puede dar, pero para cambiar la dimensionalidad del array, puedes probar lo siguiente...

```
<?php
  $array_type_services_example = [
      'fabricante'=>['company-1-a','company-2-a'],
      'instalador' =>['company-1-b','company-2-b'],
      'distribuidor' =>['company-1-c','company-2-c']
  ];
  $array_final = [];

  $num_elementos = count($array_type_services_example['fabricante']);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $num_elementos; $i++) {
      $array_final[$i] = [$array_type_services_example['fabricante'][$i],
                          $array_type_services_example['instalador'][$i],
                          $array_type_services_example['distribuidor'][$i]
                         ];
  }

  echo print_r($array_final);
?>
```

Por supuesto, para eso todos los elementos del array original (fabricante, instalador, distribuidor...) han de tener el mismo número de elementos. Pero en fin... si todo es así, la cosa es ver cuántos elementos va a tener el `$array_final` a partir de, por ejemplo, el array de `fabricante` del original, y despues ir alimentando el final con cada uno del original.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Me ha servido, que complejo lo estaba enfocando yo  y la solución ha sido excelente. Muchas Gracias Crack @VFG.

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirva. Por supuesto... se puede mejorar, porque por ejemplo poner lo de `['fabricante','instalador','distribuidor'...]` en un array puede ser útil si al final la estructura va a cambiar (o incluso sin cambios). Pero te he pueso una solución directa para enfocar lo que preguntabas. Si te vale, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Me vale y he marcado! solo que no tengo la reputación necesaria para que contabilice, pero menciona que se tendrá en cuenta!

Comment: @brajinhanna no has marcado el tick de la aceptación, que aparece más abajo, sino un voto positivo seguramente. Pulsa en [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas, asi como este otro enlace: [tour] para entender en dos minutos el funcionamiento global del sitio, gracias.

Comment: Tenías razón @masterguru. Leído la documentación que me has envíado y aceptado ya la respuesta.